# improper placing of css?

Tags: magento2, css, frontend

Below code won't work when i put it in **Content -> Homepage -> Show/Hide Editor**

```
 @media (min-width: 768px), print
    .nav-sections { 
        margin-bottom :0;
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add :

```
<style>

  @media (min-width: 768px){
        .nav-sections { 
            margin-bottom :0px;
         }
     }

</style>
```

Comment: @PiedPiper, You are welcome. Happy to hear from you.